# Jetpack compose deeplink handling branch.io

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, branch.io, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm using branch.io for handling deep links. Deep links can contain custom metadata in a form of JsonObject. The data can be obtained by setting up a listener, inside `MainActivity#onStart()` which is triggered when a link is clicked.

```
   override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Branch
        .sessionBuilder(this)
        .withCallback { referringParams, error ->
            if (error == null) {
                val eventId = referringParams?.getString("id")
                    
                //Here I would like to navigate user to event screen
            } else {
                Timber.e(error.message)
            }
        }
        .withData(this.intent?.data).init()
}
```

When I retrieve `eventId` from `referringParams` I have to navigate the user to the specific event. When I was using Navigation components with fragments I could just do:

```
findNavController(R.id.navHost).navigate("path to event screen")
```

But with compose is different because I can't use `navController` outside of Composable since its located in `MainActivity#onCreate()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        
        //I cant access navController outside of composable function
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "HomeScreen",
        ) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I navigate the user to a specific screen from `MainActivity#onStart()` when using jetpack compose navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rememberNavController` has pretty simple implementation: it creates `NavHostController` with two navigators, needed by Compose, and makes sure it's restored on configuration change.

Here's how you can do the same in your activity, outside of composable scope:

```
private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
private val navControllerBundleKey = "navControllerBundleKey"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    navController = NavHostController(this).apply {
        navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
        navigatorProvider.addNavigator(DialogNavigator())
    }

    savedInstanceState
        ?.getBundle(navControllerBundleKey)
        ?.apply(navController::restoreState)

    setContent {
        // pass navController to NavHost
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putBundle(navControllerBundleKey, navController.saveState())
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! One more thing. With this approach, when a deep link is clicked, starting screen of the app is shown (home screen), and after that user is navigated to the desired screen (event screen). Is there a way I could navigate the user directly to the event screen? Same as I would open a deep link that is defined in composable

Comment: @TemZy you can call `navController.navigate` a couple times in a row to create the stack you need: `navController.navigate(Destinations.Home); navController.navigate(Destinations.Next)`. Only the last one will be actually drawn

Comment: It doesnt work like that in my case. In my NavGraph definition I set the starting screen to either Home screen or Login screen (depending on userLoggedIn state). When deeplink is clicked the user is navigated to the home or login screen. Then branch.io callback is triggered which is set in MainActiivty#onStart(). After data is retrieved from deeplink i call navController.navigate("eventScreen/$eventId"). First home screen is shown and then event screen

Comment: @TemZy Not sure how exactly your library works, if you know that app is opened via a deep link, you can start with an empty screen route until it's resolved, then you can call `popBackStack` to remove this empty route from the stack before adding home and your deep route to the stack